# How to deploy only javadocs to remote repository after deploying artifact in maven 3?

Tags: maven, javadoc

I would like to speed up artifacts building process including javadocs but most important is time when artifacts will be ready to use without javadocs. I'd like to build and deploy first all artifacts and when they will be ready then I'd like to create and deploy javadocs for them.

Is there a solution to separate deploying javadocs from deploying artifacts?

I found a command "deploy:deploy-file" and I suppose that it might work for manual deploying javadocs but it seems to be very inconvenient. Is it a good direction to resolve my problem?